# How to read a List<> from an XML file using C#? (XNA based issue)

Tags: c#, xml, list, xna

I'm quite new to XML and XNA and have ran into a stumbling block in order to read a list That i'm outputting to store a tile map that has numerous different layers

My XML looks like this (just a sample):

```
<XnaContent xmlns:Maps="TileEditorLibrary.Maps">
 <Asset Type="Maps:TileMap">
    <R>
      <Item>
        <C>
          <Item>
            <E>1</E>
            <ID>8</ID>
            <B>8</B>
            <H />
            <T />
          </Item>
          <Item>
            <E>1</E>
            <ID>8</ID>
            <B>8</B>
            <H />
            <T />
          </Item>
        </C>
      </Item>
    </R>
  </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

My code to read it looks something like this but i'm beat as to where to go with it next:

```
public void LoadContent(XDocument doc, TileMap myMap)
    {
        XDocument mapDoc = doc;
        TileMap map = myMap;

        foreach (XElement element in mapDoc.Element("R").Elements("Item").Elements("C"))
        {
             foreach (XElement mapValue in mapDoc.Element("Item").Elements())
                {
                    if (mapValue.Name.Equals("E"))
                    {
                    //do something
                    }
                    else if (mapValue.Name.Equals("ID"))
                    {
                    }
                    else if (mapValue.Name.Equals("B"))
                    {
                    }
                    else if (mapValue.Name.Equals("H"))
                    {
                    }
                    else if (mapValue.Name.Equals("T"))
                    {
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

At the moment i'm running the app to see that it is getting the doc alright and able to parse the information but it is throwing a null object reference

I apologise if this seems quite vague but due to my inexperience with XML i'm not sure what other info might help any prospective advisor

If there is anything else that might help please ask and i'll try to explain

Many thanks

Barry

Comment: What line is throwing the `null object reference` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might give you some food for thought:

```
public void LoadContent(XDocument doc, TileMap myMap)
{
    var lookup = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>()
    {
        { "E", v => { Console.WriteLine("E  = " + v); } },
        { "ID", v => { Console.WriteLine("ID = " + v); } },
        { "B", v => { Console.WriteLine("B  = " + v); } },
        { "H", v => { Console.WriteLine("H  = " + v); } },
        { "T", v => { Console.WriteLine("T  = " + v); } },
    };

    var actions =
        from e in doc.Root
            .Element("Asset")
            .Element("R")
            .Elements("Item")
            .Elements("C")
        from mv in e
            .Elements("Item")
            .Elements()
        let name = mv.Name.ToString()
        let value = mv.Value
        select new Action(() => lookup[name](value));

    foreach (var a in actions)
        a.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Thanks,hopefully can get this sorted now

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is read up on XML [serialization and deserialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swxzdhc0.aspx).
That way you can create a class which represents the XML and deserialize it directly without any XML parsing.

[Her](http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=173)e is an example how to do it.